# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I am getting the following error when I try to create a state machine based on my state machine definition:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation: 'role' is not authorized to create managed-rule.
```

The creation code:

```
state_machine = sfn_client.create_state_machine(
    name = 'state-machine',
    definition = state_machine_def,
    roleArn = SFN_ROLE,
)
```

My IAM role that I use contains all necessary permissions as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-create-iam-role.html). What kind of managed-rule does it need to have a permission to create?

Comment: So have you applied a policy to the role? Can you share the IAM policy attached to the role?

Comment: I have the following policies attached to the role: 

 AWSLambdaRole 
 CloudWatchFullAccess 

 + Custom policies that allow full AWS batch/ ECR access as well as pass the role

Answer (score 7):

The reason was that **CloudWatchFullAccess** policy attached to the *SFN_ROLE* has not enough permissions for Step Functions workflow to post events into CloudWatch. Once I replaced it with **CloudWatchEventsFullAccess** everything works ok.

Comment: It looks like CloudWatchEventsFullAccess gives the CFN_ROLE full access to CWE "Action": "events:*", "Resource": "*". Were you able to narrow down the exact permissions required?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is this

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "events:PutTargets",
            "events:PutRule",
            "events:DescribeRule"
        ],
        "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:events:[[region]]:[[accountId]]:rule/StepFunctionsGetEventsForStepFunctionsExecutionRule"
        ]
    }
```

According to [AWS Step Function nested workflow Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/stepfunctions-iam.html), you need to add the specific rule for the step function role to listen and create events `StepFunctionsGetEventsForStepFunctionsExecutionRule` is the rule you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have missed adding the right policy to the IAM role. Here is a policy from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concept-create-iam-advanced.html) that allows you to create, list state machines.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "states:ListStateMachines",
        "states:ListActivities",
        "states:CreateStateMachine",
        "states:CreateActivity"
      ],
      "Resource": [ 
        "arn:aws:states:*:*:*" 
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ 
        "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam:::role/my-execution-role"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```